# Select rows where any of field's values matches values from array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty complicated task. I need to select rows which match any of an array's value - BUT the field contains many comma-seperated values as well.

```
$teamlist = "25,26,27,28,29,30"

MYSQL-Row 1 = "26,29,31,35,36"
MYSQL-Row 2 = "30,31,32,36,39"
MYSQL-Row 3 = "31,35,36,37,38"
MYSQL-Row 4 = "23,26,29,30,31"
```

As result Rows 1,2 and 4 should be selected.

I tried something like:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_meta WHERE team IN '".$ids."'");
```

But that only works if the fields only contain one id, not multiple. I am stuck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Start with your database design. It is incorrect.

Comment: There's a vote to reopen. It seems that @Strawberry may not have used the right duplicate to close the question with. [That Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) is more opinionated oriented if you ask me. That vote to reopen isn't mine, since if it would have been, it would have already been reopened.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You *could* pass your parameters as a derived table and then use  `find_in_set()` to search the csv column:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
    select 25 team_id
    union all select 26
    union all select 27
    ...
) x on find_in_set(x.team_id, t.team)
```

This leaves you with the work of building the derived table from your application. In very recent versions of MySQL, the [`VALUES()` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) makes the task a litte easier:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (values row(26),row(27), ...) x(team_id)
    on find_in_set(x.team_id, t.team)
```

However, you *should* not be storing lists in a database columns. This is hurtful in many ways, as explained in [this famous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/10676716). You should be storing each value of the each list on a separate row.

Comment: The answer given appears to answer the question. Have you noticed the vote to reopen and [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644027/select-rows-where-any-of-fields-values-matches-values-from-array#comment107291952_60644027) under the question?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: thanks. Yes questions related to CSV tend to get closed as duplicate to this other question (which I linked in my answer by the way), while relevant answers may exists in some cases.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: from your comment, I understand that only one vote mysql gold badge bearer is needed to reopen, is that so?

Comment: Welcome. Yes, given that that member has it for a given tag that was originally tagged  by the OP. In your opinion, should the question be reopened?

Comment: It seems that the question was already reopened before I commented above this one.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: I was wondering - but usually I tend not to make use of the gold badges powers...

Comment: Ok. Well, that badge is given for a reason and the many questions that come up more often are usually closed with proper duplicates. I tend to think that I am not abusing that privilege. Some tell me when I may have closed with an invalid link and it gets resolved rather fast and friendly like :-)